# Autocomplete results showing behind the form

Tags: ajax

How can I make the autocomplete search results appear above all elements on the page?

I have 2 forms on one page, the top form has the autocomplete text field. Immediately below that is another form. When the autocomplete results show, they are behind the second form.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is it a template or a css issue?

Comment: im not quite sure..maybe a CSS issue.. i should mention that I have a custom output of autocomplete results . I will update my post and include it there.

Thanks!

Comment: a link to a test page would help tremendously. but it looks like a styling issue

Answer (score 0):

I can only speculate as to how you've styled up the second form, but it might be its z-index is higher than that of the autocomplete dropdown.

Trying setting a higher `z-index` for the autocomplete div in your stylesheet:

```
#autocomplete {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: i tried this but it didn't worked.

Comment: You could also try targeting the DIV you're wrapping around the results:

    `.ac-results {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1000;
    }`